# Simplest Java, I have simple code with Bicycle and Human

Tags: java

Human has String named mName which is used in constructor, and Bicycle has String mOwner, I need to link one to another, Im new in this (programming) so Im not sure about what I should read about to understand better.

I created findOwner method that returns me mOwner, and declared mName "Dave" in Human's constructor... can I somehow make findOwner method return me current Human object's value?

sorry for my English and thank you)

Here's my code:

```
public class Human {

    public String mName;

    public Human(String name){
        mName = name;
    }
}

/* this one is my Bicycle */

public class Hecaniv {

private String mOwner;
private int mSpeed;
private int mShift;
private int mWheels;

public Hecaniv(int shift, int speed, int wheels){
    mSpeed = speed;
    mShift = shift;
    mWheels = wheels;

}
public int currentSpeed(){
    return mSpeed;
}

public int currentShift(){
    return mShift;
}

public int numOfWheels(){
    return mWheels;
}

public String findOwner(){
    return mOwner;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your code instead of trying to describe it?

Comment: sure, sorry again for bothering :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the name of the owner, you can just have the owner object itself as a field of `Bicycle`.

```
class Human {...}

class Bicycle {

    Human owner;

    public Bicycle(Human owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public Human findOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
}
```